# IndentationError : unexpected indent (views.py, line 40)

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am doing python and i cant solve this error as it looks good. it displays error in else statement.
I have following code:

```
def getName():
    cur = django.db.connections['oprs'].cursor()
    #Execute a trivial SQL query which returns the name of 
    #all countries contained in 'world'
    cur.execute("SELECT * from available ")
    tmp = cur.fetchall()
    #Clean-up after ourselves
    for col in tmp:
        one_1 = col[2]
        one_2 = col[3]
  # one_3 = col[7]
  # two_1 = col[5]
  # two_2 = col[6]
  # two_3 = col[7]
    cur.close()
# x1 = 0, x2 = 0, x3 = 0
    if one_1 == 1:
        x1 = 1
    else:
        x1 = 0
    x5 = 5  
    if one_2 == 1:
        x2 = 1
    else:
        x2 = 0
# if one_2 == 1:
    # x2 = 1
# else:
    # x2 = 0
# if one_3 == 1:
    # x3 = 1
```

Error:

```
else:
    x2 = 0
```

Thank you

Regards,
Gami

Comment: Have you tried deleting that line? Or the nearest lines?

Comment: thnks for reply....no i haven't yet. but it shows error in last e of (else:)

Comment: There kind of errors are weird, you may have mixed tabs and spaces, take some minutes and check that.

Comment: simple if else code is right... then why does it show error...

Comment: @Christian, PEP8 recommends [spaces over tabs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: You are right, I read that yesterday but I confused the words.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indentation is everything in python. The problem that you face is the mixing of tabs and spaces in the code that you are using. Realign everything and use either tabs or spaces